# Poisson approximation for the probability calculation

Tags: probability, self-study, python, binomial-distribution

Problem: there are $N$ machines and probability $P$ that a machine is not working. Task: calculate the probability that more than $X$ machines are going to be broken if $N$ is increased. In addition, I have to plot a distribution of the broken machines number for a specific $N$.

Here is what I did.

The probability that more than $X$ machines are broken is:

```
m = N*P
1-poisson.cdf(x, m)
```

And in order to plot a distribution for this variable I have to generate random variables with `poisson.rvs(m, N)` and then plot a histogram.

Am I correct in my speculations here?

Comment: Maybe I am not aware of some new R packages, but do functions `possion.cdf` and `poisson.rvs` really exist in R?

Comment: I didn't use an R tag for this question. It's Python.

Comment: I apologize for not noticing the "python" tag.  The problem actually can be dealt with analytically (known as [Poisson limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem)).  But do keep in mind that the assumption "$np_n \to \lambda$" in the theorem.  Under your setting (i.e., fixed $P$), the binomial probabilities won't converge to Poisson.

Answer (score 1):

(We're both assuming whether one machine is broken is independent of whether another is broken, which seems reasonable to me.)

The total number of machines is fixed, so the number of broken machines will follow a binomial distribution, not a Poisson.

Comment: Correct, I already understood that. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized how to correctly answer this simple question.

First, a cumulative distribution function gives the probability that a variable takes values less or equal to some specific value. Therefore, it is correct to use this function.

Second, as Joe stated in his answer, it is indeed better to use a binomial distribution instead of the Poisson distribution. `binom.cdf(X, N, P)` will return a probability that X or less machines are will be broken. In order to get the probability that more than X will be broken, I need to subtract it from 1: `1-binom.cdf(X, N, P)`. In other words, I was right in choosing a `cdf` function, but I did not think about the binomial distribution.